# iOs get all aps that can open directions (apple maps, google maps... )

Tags: ios, google-maps, localization, maps, apple-maps

I have a button in my app that opens a map app with directions how to drive there.
I have Apple Maps working and working on Google Maps integration. But if the user has other apps that can open directions I would like to give him a choice of all of them.

Is there a way to programatically figure out all the apps that can open maps/directions?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Not that I am aware of that will still allow you to get approved by Apple. iOS applications currently don't get to access this sort of information due to the sandboxed environment. You can see if any of the other popular maps applications have publicly available SDK's for you to integrate into your application.